# Inserting Multi-Level Unordered List with ExecCommand

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, execcommand

I have a javascript WYSIWYG editor I'm creating using "execCommand" and I'm wondering how to go about creating a multi-leveled bullet list using this command.

Currently I have a button which executes this code on the editor to create an unordered list:

`WYSIWYG.document.execCommand('InsertUnorderedList',false,'NewUL');`

My problem is that if I want to create a sub level of bullets by pressing the button the javascript obviously just closes the UL.

Any ideas as to how I could create a sub-unordered list?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use the `indent` and `outdent` commands while selecting the items you want to change:

```
WYSIWYG.document.execCommand('indent', false, null);
```